# Unity check if collider is type of spawned prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i want to check if a spawned Block (prefab) collides with my trigger collider but what i wrote doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows how to correctly check if the colliding GameObject is a Block?

Thanks in Advance. :)

Check:

```
using System;
using GameOver;
using UnityEngine;

public class gameOver : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public DeathScreen deathScreen;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.gameObject.GetType() == typeof(Block))
        {
            deathScreen.Setup();
        } 
    }
}
```

Block:

```
using System;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int _hitsRemaining = 5;

    private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
    private TextMeshPro text;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        text = GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>();
        UpdateVisualState();
    }

    private void UpdateVisualState()
    {
        text.SetText(_hitsRemaining.ToString());
        _spriteRenderer.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(0.35f, 1f, 0.67f), new Color(0.04f, 1f, 0.96f), _hitsRemaining / 10f);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        _hitsRemaining--;

        if (_hitsRemaining > 0)
            UpdateVisualState();
        else
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    internal void SetHits(int hits)
    {
        _hitsRemaining = hits;
        UpdateVisualState();
    }
}
```

Block Prefab:
[image]

Collider:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the collided object is an instantiated Block (or any Block really), you check for the existence of the Block component:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.GetComponent<Block>() != null)
    {
        deathScreen.Setup();
    } 
}
```

Additionally, with one of your collides being a trigger, OnCollisionEnter2D will not be called. Either switch both to non-triggers if you can, or use OnTriggerEnter2D - but then one of your objects has to have a Rigidbody2D as well ([source](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)), so it is really up to what you are designing.